# Can moisture travel through a microporous filler and fuel mould growth?

Tags: mold

I would like to use this product to fill holes due to it bring good for sensitive people:  https://auropaint.co.uk/product/natural-wall-filler-no-329/

However it says that it is micro poros which means it allows water vapours to go through.

Does this mean if I use it to fill a hole in my bathroom, and there is mold inside the wall, moisture will be able to travel through the filler and fuel mold growth on the other side?  Conversely can mold vapors travel through the filler also?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the technical data, they recommend another product to fill holes, cracks, etc. Then this product is recommended for smoothing out surfaces, bonding to various substrates, etc.

If there’s moisture in the wall or coming through the wall, it will allow staining, mold, etc.